# Can Jenkins config.xml have a property file?

Tags: xml, ant, jenkins

I'm looking to manage the `config.xml` files on our Jenkins servers with Puppet. However, there are very specific entries that are unique for each server such as jobs, folders, passwords, etc...

My question is whether or not Jenkins allows the import or including of properties defined in a different file much like how Ant does, which will allow us to manage the common entries in the `config.xml`, and extract the unique entries out to the properties file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this yet, but I just found this:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin

It looks like it's applied at the job-level only, and not at the global Jenkins level.  Is that enough for your needs?